# procedure to add count() in group_concat()

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a below procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ptl_head`()
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT(
         'MAX(CASE WHEN month(alloc_date) = ''',
         month(alloc_date),
         ''' THEN emp_code END) `',
         month(alloc_date),'_',year(alloc_date),
         '`' 
         )

 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM daily_report;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT emp_code, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM daily_report
                    GROUP BY emp_code');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I would like to add count of emp_code as output but i get emp_code as output.Someone help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

What about -

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT emp_code, ', @sql ' 
                   FROM daily_report
                   GROUP BY emp_code
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT "Count", COUNT(*), month(alloc_date), '_', year(alloc_date)
                   FROM daily_report');
```

Comment: actually i wanted to display the count of emp_code for that particular column i am getting the emp_code as value in the respective column

Comment: So you just want to show the count that how much emp_code you get?

Comment: Exactly what you say

Comment: i get an error the used select statements has different number of columns

Comment: @HariPriya, Try Now.